# Invoking python in AWS lambda import error

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I am trying to invoke a python script in AWS lambda function. I have created a virtual env for python and installed pandas,pymongo etc module which are needed. Here is my invokepython.js:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    exec("env/bin/python kinesisconsumer.py '"+ JSON.stringify(event) +"'", function(error, stdout) {
    console.log('Python returned: ' + stdout + '.');
    context.done(error, stdout);
});
};
```

I have installed `virtualenv` and created a env using it. Using `env/bin/pip install pandas` I have installed pandas. I have zipped env folder and my scripts together and deployed it to AWS lambda but getting error.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Command failed: Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"kinesisconsumer.py\", line 4, in <module>\n    import pandas as pd\n  File \"/var/task/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py\", line 13, in <module>\n    \"extensions first.\".format(module))\nImportError: C extension: libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first.\n",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"kinesisconsumer.py\", line 4, in <module>",
    "    import pandas as pd",
    "  File \"/var/task/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py\", line 13, in <module>",
    "    \"extensions first.\".format(module))",
    "ImportError: C extension: libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first.",
    "",
    "ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:658:15)",
    "ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)",
    "maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)",
    "Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)"
  ]
```

I need to use pandas on AWS lambda. How should I tackle this problem. Any help appreciated!!!

Comment: Use wheels, already complied.

Comment: @e-nouri I didnt get you.How do I use wheels

Comment: wheels are python packages/libs that are already compiled, the pip will only unpackage them in your env.

Comment: why don't you use node.js directly ?!

Comment: @e-nouri I need to do some dataframe operations and there are many scripts written in python already. How is wheels different from pip installation. I mean pandas is installed in my virtualenv.

Comment: also I can not find wheel for pandas for linux

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93966/discussion-between-sau-and-e-nouri).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did everything on Amazon Linux as I was doing on my ubuntu machine. Its working. Explanation [here](https://markn.ca/2015/10/python-extension-modules-in-aws-lambda/)

> In order to work in AWS Lambda, extension modules need to be compiled for Amazon Linux x86_64"